# A shared Makefile dependency is only run once

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

### TL; DR

A dependency shared by multiple targets is only invoked once.

Why?

### Summary

In this tiny `Makefile` example, I expect `deploy-everywhere` to deploy `staging-repo` code to *staging*, and `prod-repo` code to *prod*.

Instead, both *staging* and *prod* get `staging-repo` code, which is, admittedly, suboptimal.

This seems to be happening because `clone-repo` is skipped / pruned when it is examined 2nd time around, as part of `deploy-to-prod` (see `-d` log output below).

Why is this happening, and can I change this behavior?

```bash
$ cat Makefile

.PHONY: deploy-everywhere deploy-to-prod deploy-to-staging clone-repo

deploy-everywhere: deploy-to-staging deploy-to-prod
    @echo "deployed everywhere"

deploy-to-prod: repo="prod-repo"
deploy-to-prod: clone-repo
    @echo "deployed to prod (from $(repo))"

deploy-to-staging: repo="staging-repo"
deploy-to-staging: clone-repo
    @echo "deployed to staging (from $(repo))"

clone-repo:
    @echo "clone-repo $(repo)"
```

### More Details (logs, version)

Here is the output from running `make`:

```
$ make deploy-everywhere
clone-repo staging-repo
deployed to staging (from staging-repo)
deployed to prod (from prod-repo) <<<<< THIS IS A LIE, WE NEVER CLONED THE PROD REPO!!
deployed everywhere <<<< RIIIIGHT.
```

Extra logging:

```
$ make -d deploy-everywhere
...
  Successfully remade target file `deploy-to-staging'.
  Considering target file `deploy-to-prod'.
   File `deploy-to-prod' does not exist.
    Pruning file `clone-repo'.          <<<< WHY? WHY?!?!?!?! WHY.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `deploy-to-prod'.
  Must remake target `deploy-to-prod'.
...
```

I am running GNU Make 3.81:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Targets in a makefile are more like nouns than like verbs.

You can achieve what you want several ways. Here is one:

```
deploy-to-prod: clone-prod-repo
    @echo "deployed to prod (from prod-repo)"

deploy-to-staging: clone-staging-repo
    @echo "deployed to staging (from staging-repo)"

clone-%-repo:
    @echo "clone $*-repo"
```

**EDIT:** All right, the `clone` operation takes multiple parameters. Here is one way to do it:

```
deploy-to-prod: PARAM1=ProdOne
deploy-to-prod: PARAM2=ProdTwo
deploy-to-prod: clone-prod-repo
    @echo "deployed to prod (from prod-repo)"

deploy-to-staging: PARAM1=StagingFirst
deploy-to-staging: PARAM2=StagingSecond
deploy-to-staging: clone-staging-repo
    @echo "deployed to staging (from staging-repo)"

clone-%-repo:
    @echo clone $*-repo with $(PARAM1) and $(PARAM2)
```

And here is another:

```
define clone-repo
@echo clone using $(1)
@echo and $(2) in some way
endef

deploy-to-prod:
    @echo $@
    $(call clone-repo, ProdOne, ProdTwo)

deploy-to-staging:
    @echo $@
    $(call clone-repo, StagingFirst, StagingSecond)
```

Comment: Thank you Beta! This is a great solution. Sadly, I don't think this will work for us, because outside of my tiny example, the actual set of parameters that we are passing into "clone-repo" is rather rich. Do you happen to know where I can read up on this? My understanding was that making my target(s) .PHONY (or running "make -B") would force those targets to always execute, but my assumption clearly does not apply to in-flight pruning logic... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To add some explanation to Beta's solution: The programmatic contract of a `make` rule is that it is an opaque update of a permanent entity in the filesystem, thereby satisfying a *"less-than"* (younger-than) relation laid down in the dependency tree. Your construction OTOH hides the dependency from `make` by passing it as a parameter. The problem that you tried to circumvent is that there is no notion for "less-than" in `make` for non-filesystem-present entities (in your case, a revision control system). 
The only question that I have is why you didn't simply add the `clone` call to each `deploy` target - if you really want to solve it as a "less-than" dependency (ie. cloning only if local repository non-existent or older) there is quite some `make` programming necessary.

EDIT after your first comment:
If I got you right, your idea of `PHONY` is a bit off (not totally, just a bit). `PHONY` is not about facilitating something across different `make` runs, it is a way to have a short-circtuit in your dependency tree. Given a chain `foo -> bar -> phony_baz` (foo depending on bar depending on phony_baz) `make` will, in the case that `foo` was the main target, first look at `bar` to see if it is older than `phony_baz` which *always* will be the case. This is because `phony_baz` itself has a `make`-implicit property that will always  yield a "younger_than" when it is compared as a prerequisite against a target (and now comes the important part:) **at the first encounter in the dependency tree**. All subsequent encounters of `phony_baz` in other branches of the tree will do the exact opposite, terminating the evaluation  right there at the phony target. This is no different from the behaviour at any other node in the dependency graph - `make` assumes that the contract which I noted above is fulfilled and no repetitive action is justified. This is the explanation for your `clone-repo` not firing a second time although it is `.PHONY` - your setup is effectively a directed acyclic graph where two edges join at the same node (which `make` is completely fine with, just worth noting), not a tree . Beta's first solution is to dynamically create two entirely unrelated nodes by parametrizing the rule, thereby returning the shape to a tree.

Comment: Thank you, Vroom. A follow up question: Marking a target `PHONY` (or running `make --always-make`) circumvents the "less-than" dependency tree check across `make` runs (running `make deploy-to-staging` and `make deploy-to-prod` separately does what I expect). However, within a single `make` run, PHONY is of no help. Do you happen to know if there is a way I can create PHONY-like behavior within a single make run (or where to read up on this)? In our real-life `Makefile`, `clone-repo` is a non-trivial operation, so it would be great to avoid replicating it under our many "deploy-to-*" targets.